# Angular navigate causing infinte loop in route guarding

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have these routes:

```
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'todos', component: TodosComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'add-todo', component: AddTodoComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path: 'todo/:id', component: TodoComponent, resolve: {
    todo: TodoResolver
  },  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [IsLoggedIn]},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
]
```

With this guard:

```
export class IsLoggedInGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private storageService: StorageService, private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    const user = this.storageService.getFromStorage('user');
    if(user) {
      this.authService.setUser(user, false);
      this.router.navigate(['todos']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Locally works fine, but when I deploy it it enters an infinite loop.

Why is there an infinte loop and how can I solve it?

Comment: What if it fails to get the user, so the guard fails and the canActivate becomes falsy, so it doesn't enter login. Usually there are different permissions when you are online than on localhost, and maybe that applies to the localStorage you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you should make sure that the IsLoggedInGuard guard is only applied to the login route, and not to any other routes. You can do this by modifying the route configuration like this:

```
{
  path: 'login',
  component: LoginComponent,
  canActivate: [IsLoggedInGuard]
},
{
  path: 'todos',
  component: TodosComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{
  path: 'add-todo',
  component: AddTodoComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{
  path: 'todo/:id',
  component: TodoComponent,
  resolve: {
    todo: TodoResolver
  },
  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
```